# How to fetch archive messages from an external component

Tags: node.js, xmpp, tigase

I'm using node-xmpp-component to build an external-xmpp-component, and I need to pull all archived messages for any given jid.

I'm able to connect and send messages, but I can't figure how to build the sanza for requesting archived messages.

Note: This is question is not about how to get archived messages,it about how to get them from an external XMPP component.

Answer (score 0):

To get message archive, you need to query it from the user account requesting the archive. As you see in XEP example ([Querying an archive](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0313.html#query)), there is no place to define which user you are acting as. It is supposed to be the user sending the XMPP packet:

```
<iq type='set' id='juliet1'>
  <query xmlns='urn:xmpp:mam:0' queryid='f27' />
</iq>
```

However, node-xmpp-component implements [XEP-0114: Jabber Component Protocol](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0114.html). The Component Protocol says basically, you can only act as the component or any usernames from that component domain:

> Once authenticated, the component can send stanzas through the server
>   and receive stanzas from the server. All stanzas sent to the server
>   MUST possess a 'from' attribute and a 'to' attribute, as in the
>   'jabber:server' namespace. The domain identifier portion of the JID
>   contained in the 'from' attribute MUST match the hostname of the
>   component. However, this is the only restriction on 'from' addresses,
>   and the component MAY send stanzas from any user at its hostname.

It means that for privacy / security reasons, a "Jabber Component" cannot send packet on behalf of the main server user.

So, you **cannot** forge the IQ packet needed to query the MAM archive as a user from a component, the reason being privacy.

You need to find another design for the feature you want to implement.